# Fill a HashSet<T> with all implementations of ISomething

Tags: c#, .net

I asking for a more smooth and nice way to do this (and/or corrections if I'm wrong here),

```
HashSet<ISomething> itemRows;

List<ISomething> PopulateItemRows()
{
    itemRows = new HashSet<ISomething>();
    itemRows.UnionWith(new SomeType1().Collection());
    itemRows.UnionWith(new SomeType2().Collection());
    itemRows.UnionWith(new SomeType3().Collection());
    itemRows.UnionWith(new SomeType4().Collection());
    return itemRows.ToList();
}
```

SomeTypeXX are all implements the ISomething.

The very best would of course be avoiding the explicit including of types. 
There can be a scenario of new implementations and this method missed to be updated.

Comment: Correction 1: `PopulateItemRows` is expected to return void, but your return statement returns a list. The signature should be `public List<ISomething> PopulateItemRows()`

Comment: Of course. Caused by some editing. Thank's for correction. Now, just some advices are missing :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a generic way to find all types implementing `ISomething`:

```
var somethingTypes = typeof(ISomething)
    .Assembly
    .GetTypes() 
    .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(ISomething))

foreach (var t in somethingTypes)
{
    var o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    var mi = (IEnumerable<ISomething>)t.GetMethod("Collection");
    if (mi != null)
    {
        var items = .Invoke(o, null);
        itemRows.UnionWith(items); 
    }
}
```

The code assumes that all types implementing `ISomething` live in the same assembly as the interface.

**Update**: Added some sanity checks based on Martins answer

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with this:

```
...
List<ISomething> instances = new List<ISomething>({new SomeType1(), new SomeType2(),...});
...
List<ISomething> PopulateItemRows()
{
    itemRows = new HashSet<ISomething>();
    foreach(ISomething instance in instances)
    {
        itemRows.UnionWith(instance.Collection());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you code is truly like this because `ISomething` looks a bit weird. Anyway, here is a solution based on reflection.

```
interface ISomething {
  IEnumerable<ISomething> Collection();
}

List<ISomething> PopulateItemRows() {
  var itemRows = new HashSet<ISomething>();
  var constructorInfos = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .Where(
      type => type.IsClass
      && !type.IsAbstract
      && typeof(ISomething).IsAssignableFrom(type)
    )
    .Select(type => type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes))
    .Where(ci => ci != null);
  foreach (var constructorInfo in constructorInfos) {
    var something = (ISomething) constructorInfo.Invoke(null);
    itemRows.UnionWith(something.Collection());
  }
}
```

Comment: A ISomething-implemented class contains a constructor that do X Y. After instantiated, the method Collection() gives a list of itself. Why weird?

Comment: The recursive nature of `ISomething` looks a bit odd to me, but obviously I don't know if you really need the recursion perhaps to describe a hierarchical structure of "somethings".

Comment: This is, in reality, a parser of a CSV file, which has to be readed as whole to keep the parent/child-Items related structure when writing it back to file.